# Have GPU Passthrough working both Windows and Linux guests but libGL SDL error linux couldn't find matching glx visual NX x2go freenx

Tags: kvm-virtualization, centos6, x11, nx, freenx

I have GPU Pass-through working with KVM qemu with both Windows 7 and CentOS guest but with Windows I can easily RDP with Remote Desktop mstsc and even run 3D accelerated apps that will make use of the OpenGL acceleration etc.

I don't care about VirtualGL and similar technologies whereby one can play games remotely, I only care about being able to use apps remotely that require a graphics card, so I simply want the openGL glx etc to run on the server and be able to login remotely with nxclient (nomachine nx or vnc/xrdp) to use those programs remotely just as its possible to do on Windows by simply doing RDP (with mstsc.exe Remote Desktop client) into the Windows 7 guest. But on Linux I keep getting errors when I try to run software that needs a GPU, errors like couldn't find matching glx visual, can't write to SDL2 window etc. And glxinfo shows "direct rendering": No

So again this works perfectly fine with Windows 7 guest, I passthrough the GPU to Windows 7 and I can Remote Desktop RDP over internet to Windows7 guest and can run OpenGL benchmark tools in Windows7 or other apps that require a GPU. But when I try to do that inside a Linux GUEST (centos 6.x) where I also passed through the GPU I get errors like couldn't find matching glx visual. Here's my glxinfo and lsmod | grep radeon driver (installed proprietary driver from ATI website). thanks!

glxinfo

```
name of display: :50.0
display: :50  screen: 0
direct rendering: No (If you want to find out why, try setting LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose)
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.2
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_hyperpipe, GLX_SGIX_swap_barrier, 
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig
client glx vendor string: ATI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_swap_control, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, 
    GLX_MESA_allocate_memory, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_MESA_swap_control, 
    GLX_MESA_swap_frame_usage, GLX_NV_swap_group, GLX_OML_swap_method, 
    GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGIX_swap_barrier, GLX_SGIX_swap_group, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, 
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_AMD_gpu_association, GLX_EXT_buffer_age
GLX version: 1.2
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_OML_swap_method, 
    GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
    GLX_SGIX_swap_barrier
OpenGL vendor string: Mesa project: www.mesa3d.org
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa GLX Indirect
OpenGL version string: 1.2 (1.5 Mesa 6.4.1)
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_ARB_depth_texture, GL_ARB_imaging, GL_ARB_multitexture, 
    GL_ARB_point_parameters, GL_ARB_point_sprite, GL_ARB_shadow, 
    GL_ARB_shadow_ambient, GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, GL_ARB_texture_env_add, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat, 
    GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, GL_ARB_window_pos, 
    GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_blend_color, GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, 
    GL_EXT_blend_logic_op, GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract, 
    GL_EXT_clip_volume_hint, GL_EXT_copy_texture, GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, 
    GL_EXT_fog_coord, GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, GL_EXT_packed_pixels, 
    GL_EXT_point_parameters, GL_EXT_polygon_offset, GL_EXT_rescale_normal, 
    GL_EXT_secondary_color, GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, 
    GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, GL_EXT_stencil_two_side, GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, 
    GL_EXT_subtexture, GL_EXT_texture, GL_EXT_texture3D, 
    GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_env_add, 
    GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, 
    GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, GL_EXT_texture_object, GL_EXT_texture_rectangle, 
    GL_EXT_vertex_array, GL_APPLE_packed_pixels, GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3, 
    GL_ATI_texture_mirror_once, GL_ATIX_texture_env_combine3, 
    GL_HP_occlusion_test, GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, 
    GL_INGR_blend_func_separate, GL_MESA_pack_invert, GL_MESA_ycbcr_texture, 
    GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_SGIX_depth_texture, 
    GL_SGIX_shadow, GL_SGIX_shadow_ambient, GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays

5 GLX Visuals
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x04f 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x050 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 16  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 None
0x051 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 16  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x052 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 16  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x053 24 sc  0  24  0  c y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None

11 GLXFBConfigs:
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x04f 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x050 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 16  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 None
0x051 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 16  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x052 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 16  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x053 24 sc  0  24  0  c y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x053  0 tc  0 128  0    y .  32 32 32 32 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x053  0 tc  0 128  0    . .  32 32 32 32 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x053  0 tc  0  64  0    y .  16 16 16 16 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x053  0 tc  0  64  0    . .  16 16 16 16 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x053  0 tc  0  32  0    y .  11 11 10  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x053  0 tc  0  32  0    . .  11 11 10  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
```

lsmod | grep radeon

```
radeon                917108  2
ttm                    80957  1 radeon
drm_kms_helper         40087  1 radeon
drm                   265638  4 radeon,ttm,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit            5935  1 radeon
i2c_core               31084  5 i2c_i801,radeon,drm_kms_helper,drm,i2c_algo_bit
```

---

Seems like VirtualGL does do something in tune to what I want. I can run 3D opengl now and get "direct rendering" saying "yes" when I use "vglrun glxinfo"
and vglrun glxgears etc. (Interestingly glxgears runs much faster on software rendering without vglrun, but that glxspheres thing does run much faster with vglrun versus using mesa software render.)

Anyway, what I discovered though is that vglrun won't work with Android Emulator because I guess it can't handle the OpenGL "ES" emulation it wants to do or some issue like that.  I can't get rid of this error:

```
Failed to open lib64EGL_translator
Failed to init_egl_dispatch
emulator: ERROR: OpenGLES initialization failed!
emulator: ERROR: OpenGLES emulation library could not be initialized!
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
```

In conclusion I see my only solution is to get my GPU pass-through working as a primary card instead of booting using emulated cirrus logic and then using the passed through AMD GPU with vglrun/virtualgl. If I remove the emulated cirruslogic then I can BOOT the host console DIRECTLY on the passed through GPU.
Then I would be able to run x11vnc or similar vnc that allows binding on the LOCAL :0 display on the passed through GPU. This means I can then just do an NX into the remote machine and once in then connect with tigervnc or turbovnc or tightvnc to the x11vnc session on the LOCAL display and this way I should have direct OPENGL on everything, entire session without having to rely on VirtualGL and vglrun which for android emulator did not work anyway, again some issue with lib64EGL translator. (and yes I had needed .so in the path and in the ldconfig etc etc the correct 64bit file was there etc, its not something simple like that, I think somehow vglrun maybe can't handle opengl es translation ? )

Anyway, my only problem now is although I did have it working before somehow, now if I try to remove cirruslogic vga from my virtual image, the virtual machine goes into a "paused state" as soon as it tries to boot. (I can modify kernel boot parameters but soon as I tell it ok boot, it goes into 'paused' state in KVM) but at least if I can fix that I can fix my android emulator problem it seems.

Comment: I may have misunderstood what VirtualGL did, I thought it sent OpenGL "from server" to my client but seems like it might be what I need if it actually intercepts a software's request to do openGL on my client side and sends the request for rendering to the 'server'.

Comment: why did you delete my answer? I did solve the problem of that error via virtualgl and vglrun so it was a valid answer and I just explained that for my ultimate goal that isn't enough and I provided a solution even for that.

Comment: if you 'delete' an answer the nice thing is to provide a reason, not to simply have a link to some generic FAQ, it comes off as arrogant